# Android USB Debugging on Ubuntu with Android Studio is flaky

Tags: android, debugging, ubuntu, android-studio, adb

The ADB can see my device via USB. Sometimes I'm able to deploy to my USB device, but many times I'm not. Android Studio attempts to copy the file to my phone, and most times it just hangs there:

```
Waiting for device. 
enter code hereTarget device: samsung-sch_i535-6a0c34e3
Uploading file
    local path: /home/shane/AndroidStudioProjects/Test1/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.shane.test1
```

Does anybody have a solution that I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than asking if anyone else has this issue can I suggest that you ask if anyone has a solution - otherwise you're just conducting a survey!

Comment: You are you implying you have a solution?

Comment: No, I am implying nothing. I am recommending that you ask for a solution rather than ask if anyone has the same problem. Aah, I see your edit. Nice one.

Comment: how do you define usb driver for your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any issues on Ubuntu 14.04, works pretty much always without problems.

However I had similar issues on different machines (on OSX)

Does `adb devices` show your phone as connected?

- If yes, then it's probably rather AS to blame. Make sure you are on the latest version (1.0.1 at the time of writing).
- If no, try `adb kill-server` and see if that changes things. Also `adb` has debug flag `ADB_TRACE` that you can set, this should give you much more information.

As a side note - make sure your cable is okay. I once spent days 'debugging' `adb` just to find out that the cable had a loose contact.

And, last but not least, try connection over Wifi and see if you have similar issues.

Happy debugging.